# Duda multiples controladores AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Supongamos que tengo lo siguiente

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
   .......
</div>
```

TestController.js

```
App.controller('TestController', ['$rootScope','$q','TestService', function($rootScope, $q, $TestService) 

    $scope.method1= function() {...}
    $scope.method2= function() {...}
    ...
    $scope.method10= function() {...}
```

Ahora, si llamo a cualquier método funcionará, pero me gustaría tener 2 controladores y que cada uno de ellos contenga 5 métodos, si tuviese 100 métodos en un solo controlador es muy dificil de mantenerlo, se puede hacer como un controller general e importar los otros?

Comment: Si necesitas crear funciones que reutilizaras en distintas páginas la mejor práctica sería crear un servicio genérico e inyectarlo en el controlador que lo requiera colega :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena forma de resolver tu problema es la creación de un **[servicio](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp)** para ser reutilizado en tu aplicación; de esta forma evitas la redundancia y la clonación de código.

Por ejemplo si necesitamos crear una función que concatene y sabemos que nos sería útil para otros controladores:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.service('miServicio', [function(){
  this.procesarCadenas = (val1, val2) => {
    return `${val1} ${val2}`;
  }
}]);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'miServicio', function($scope, miServicio){
  $scope.st1 = '';
  $scope.st2 = '';
  
  $scope.click = (val1, val2) => {
    $scope.result = miServicio.procesarCadenas($scope.st1, $scope.st2);
  }
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
      <label for="" class="control-label">Cadena #1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="st1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group mr-2">
      <label for="" class="control-label">Cadena #2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="st2">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="click(str1, str2)">Aplicar servicio</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="control-label text-success">Resultado: {{result}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora si necesitas utilizarla en otro controlador sólo necesitas inyectar el servicio en dicho **controller**

```
app.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', 'miServicio', function($scope, miServicio)]{ 
   ... 
})
```

Mucho más práctico =)

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: un controlador puede tener varios servicios?, es decir:
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'miServicio', 'miServicio2', function($scope, miServicio, miServicio2){

Comment: Sin ningún problema! Puedes tener N servicios inyectados en tus controladores

Answer (score 0):

No hay ningún problema en definir más de un controlador en el mismo módulo o si querés, en la misma página.

En el mismo módulo se definen así:

```
    angular.module("myapp",[]);
    .controller('cont1',function($scope){
      $scope.nombre="";
       });

   .controller('cont2',function($scope){
    $scope.apellido="";
    });
```

Para definir múltiples controladores también podes hacerlo cada uno en su hoja propia o todos en la misma hoja:

```
angular.module("myapp").controller('cont1'['$scope', function($scope){

}]);

angular.module("myapp").controller('cont2'['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

Pero las mejores practicas indican que definas todo en files separados:

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module("myapp",[]); // dentro de [] se incluyen las dependencias del módulo
```

y luego le pases las dependencias a los controladores:

```
.controller('ctrlName', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```